# Drag the clone of dropped elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have tried to drag the dropped element which is a clone of the dragged element, but when I drag the element it create a another element in the page. Here is my code..

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".component").draggable({
        //  use a helper-clone that is append to 'body' so is not 'contained' by a pane
        helper:  function () { 
            return jQuery(this).clone().appendTo('body').css({'zIndex':5}); 
        },
        cursor: 'move'
    });

    jQuery('.ui-layout-center').droppable({
        activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        accept:  '.component',
        drop:  function(event, ui) {
            jQuery(this).append(jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().draggable()); 
        }
    });
});
```

Is there any missing command which makes every drag make a new clone?

Answer (score 1):

You should had a class in order to indicate that element has been dropped and that you can move it but you should not clone it.
You can have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/njYqA/ .
In the handler for drop, I have just replace by this code :

```
if (!ui.draggable.hasClass("dropped"))
    jQuery(this).append(jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().addClass("dropped").draggable());
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(this).append(jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().draggable());` Did you forget `.clone()`